# A product matching the following parameters cannot be found during VS Installation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've tried all the solution available at StackOverflow and VS developer community but I'm unable to resolve the error saying.

```
A product matching the following parameters cannot be found:

channelId:  VisualStudio.15.Release
productId:  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community
```

Here are the solutions that I've tried.

- tried deleting the VS folder in Program Files
- tried running `InstallCleanup.exe -i with cmd` (as administrator)
- tried running `InstallCleanup.exe -f with cmd` (as administrator)
- tried deleting VS packages from Program Data
- tried installing with new and old both packages

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this problem and was able to solve with following steps

1. Open a command prompt with admin privileges
2. Run following command (this will clean up previous install cache. -full option is important)
   `"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe" -full`
3. Restart the installer

Hope this helps. Just to add, I did not have to uninstall VS 2015 for this to work.

Comment: This worked for having the same issue with VS2017.  Link provides more detailed information on this as well:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96079/a-product-matching-the-following-parameters-cannot-2.html

Answer (score 10):

For people looking for solutions to VS2019 issue, The InstallCleanup.exe is under "Installer" directory instead of its subdir.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe" -full
```

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps and your issue will be resolved:

**UNINSTALL**

1. Please navigate to C:\Program Files x86 and search for a Microsoft Visual Studio folder. Then right click and delete that folder.
2. Then remove only Visual Studio folders from these 2 locations, if they are there:
   `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft`
   `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft`
3. Lastly, please type regedit in the lower left search field to access the registry editor... Once it's open navigate to `HKEY LOCAL MACHINE > SOFTWARE > MICROSOFT` and check for a Visual Studio folder there. If you see one there, right click and delete the folder.

**BEFORE INSTALLING AGAIN**

Before you attempt your installation again, make certain you are following these guidelines below:

1. Restart.
2. Make sure your Windows is up-to-date, check for any pending Windows Updates.
3. Disable any anti-virus/firewall temporarily (this includes Windows Defender). Installer needs unblocked access to the internet to access Microsoft Servers.
4. Clean up the (C:\Windows\Temp) folder.
5. When launching the Installer, Right Click and select "Run as Admin"
   Overlooking the above steps results in most installations failures.