# Issue installing Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 - "A product matching the following parameters cannot be found" during installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This error presents itself immediately upon first launch of the program following the attempted install.

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnT1K.jpg)

I have ran `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe -full` and then re-ran the installer and the issue still presents itself.

I have tried the [solutions here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96079/a-product-matching-the-following-parameters-cannot-2.html) and they did not resolve my issue.

I also tried both of [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578038/a-product-matching-the-following-parameters-cannot-be-found-during-vs-installati).

Any guidance here or things to try next will be very helpful!

Here are my log files from when I tried this in March. They're old, but re-running this installation still shows the exact same error.

https://pastebin.com/7D2JwGKF

```
for i in 12 do this.function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A product matching the following parameters cannot be found during VS Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578038/a-product-matching-the-following-parameters-cannot-be-found-during-vs-installati)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

Open a command prompt with admin privileges
Run following command (this will clean up previous install cache. -full option is important) "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe" -full
Restart the installer

[A product matching the following parameters cannot be found during VS Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578038/a-product-matching-the-following-parameters-cannot-be-found-during-vs-installati)